# Fixed image size despite device pixel ratio

Tags: javascript, android, css

I am trying to find a way to have same size (actual 250 pixels) for an image across all devices/browsers. My problem is with **device pixel ratio**. On devices with device pixel ratio higher than 1, the image is shown tiny and when you zoom in, it grows bigger (Same would happen if you would zoom into the ordinary browser).

So, my question is: Is there a way to achieve a constant (actual) size image, by using CSS (or less favorably JavaScript)? Is it possible to fix the size and don't allow it to go any bigger or smaller?

Comment: i dont think its the image that is zooming out.. i think your page is zoomed out on your device. Images are always the same pixels, even with higher pixel ratio's. You will just get blurry images, but the size will be correct.

Comment: Have you set viewport?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: @LaurensKling I want physically image to stay the same size. No bigger, no smaller. I understand that logical size changes when you zoom in or out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is to set a consitant ratio of the viewport.

Add this to your `<head>` :

`<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">`

Comment: This might have been a solution for a similar problem, but I want everything to scale, except for the image. So it isn't really what I'm looking for.

Comment: now i understand what you are asking! So you want the user to be able to zoom the page, but the image stay in one fixed size. I dont know how you would be able to do so, and i think it would be a really weird interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate the image in a div like this:

```
<div id='imageDiv'><img src='theImage.png' class='imageclass' /></div>
```

And then set the size of the div and position of the image with CSS like this:

```
#imageDiv {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.imageclass {
    position: absolute;
}
```

This should keep it the same size for you across all devices.

Comment: It won't really help, as this would only set logical size, not physical. When you check with javascript, it seems to be 250 px, but it really isn't.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution I can think of, without heavy (but a little bit) use of javascript is like:

1. put this after `</body>`:

   ```js
   <script type="text/javascript" id="script-after-body">
   document.body.style.setProperty('--device-pixel-ratio', devicePixelRatio);
   window.addEventListener('resize',e=>{
     document.body.style.setProperty('--device-pixel-ratio', devicePixelRatio);
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. put this in style of the `<img>`:

   ```css
   width: calc(250px / var(--device-pixel-ratio));
   ```

Compared to a heavily scripted solution, this solution has a limitation that you have to specify a value of the expected image size in CSS.